# How to ignore html in Tester->click in codeception?

Tags: codeception

I have a html string that looks like that :

```
<div>firstname <br> <span>lastname</span></div>
```

is there a way to run on my Tester :

```
$I->click('firstname lastname');
```

while ignoring the tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath like:

```
//div[contains(.,'firstname') and contains(.,'lastname')]
```